# How send a file with App Inventor to a given location

Tags: php, android, app-inventor

I am following Taifun's tutorial (https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php) on how to post files to a php server from within an App Inventor app.

I would like to know how I could do the same but simultaneously move them to a given location, like a new created folder named after the person who posted it.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question right, I also needed the same functionality in my project, and this is what I did,

This is the fileUpload.php file

```
<?php
$target_path="uploads/".$_POST['username']."/";
if (!is_dir($target_path)) 
// is_dir - tells whether the filename is a directory
{
    //mkdir - tells that need to create a directory
    mkdir($target_path);
}
$target_path=$target_path.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
try {
    //throw exception if can't move the file
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        throw new Exception('Could not move file');
    }
    echo $target_path;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Upload Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

while this is the file to test your uploads from a browser,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File Upload Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fileUpload.php" method="POST">            
            <br/>Choose a file to upload: <br/><input name="image" type="file" /><br />
            User Name: <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I think you can easily figure out how to handle this from android.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Marc You should accept the answer if it helped you and if it didn't at least explain your issue further in the comments.